# Latex template for quickly writing summaries of courses

Tags: latex

For some courses I take, we are allowed to write a summary and to used it at the exam. The summary allowed is usually limited to something like ten A4 pages. I quickly googled for latex templatex, but I couldn't find anything useful so far.

The template should allow to used the full space available on an A4 paper, by default latex documents usually have large borders. I guess I'm not the first person looking for this kind of template, so please post any links if you know good templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your margins pretty easily using the geometry package (which should be part of most latex distributions I believe) http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/

You'll probably also need one of the multiple column layouts and `amsmath` packages.

You can find a bunch of details on page layout here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

I'd probably use something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
... MY STUFF HERE ...
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Original version was trying to use the plain style, which seems to not exist. Also had the usepackages inside the document rather than the preamble, and had some spelling mistakes. Won't look useful until you fill it with some stub data... head over to [lipsum.com](http://lipsum.com/) for some filler text.

Comment: Sounds good, thx for the answer.. maybe I can quickly write my own template.

Comment: Fixed some typos and the plain issue. Hopefully thats fixed it for you Nils.